Experience Space: Create a Content Manager Like Panel in Custom Primary Navigation Page
Is is possible to create a side panel like the left content manger panel in a custom primary navigation page. So the goal is to achieve the same layout as Content for a custom primary navigation.

The primary navigation or tabs are the top of Experience Space are an extension point. Is the idea for users to go to this new tab and then see a navigation tree there, separate from the out-of-the-box tree?

Yes, it would be visually the same, but the content like navigation links and other data would be controlled/displayed from the created extension
